# How do I show a ViewController and then dismiss it to show a UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

When there is no account setup in `iPad` mail app, it opens mail clients to choose from? After choosing the mail client, the view controller is dismiss modally and `UISplitViewController` is displayed.

I want working on an `iPad` application, where I have to show a `ViewController` first and dismissed it to show `UISpiltViewController`. I wonder, how it is done.

I could only lunch `UISplitViewController` at first by setting it to rootView controller. Here is my code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.



    PopViewController * menuVC = [[PopViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UINavigationController * navMenue = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuVC];

    DetialViewController *delainVC =[[DetialViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController * navdetail = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:delainVC];

    UISplitViewController *splitVC = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navMenue,navdetail, nil];


    self.window.rootViewController = splitVC;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I learn that you have to always set `UISplitViewController` as your rootViewController. But my goal is to open a ViewController before `UISplitViewController`. Exactly like `iPad` mail app when there is no account setup.

Comment: I think you've got it right.  After setting the root view controller, decide whether you want to put a modal view controller on top of it.

Comment: I did open a modal view controller on top of it. It looks kind of weird because  I could see SplitViewController before the modal view is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since - (void)viewDidLoad is called before -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated . while opening the modal view controller with no animation in view did load method. solved the problem. And there was no glance of UISplitViewcontroller. Below is the code. This code should be placed in detailview controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self checkLogIn];

}
```

wrote a function to check if user is already logged in

```
-(void) checkLogIn{

  if(notLoggedIn){
        ViewController * VC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:VC animated:NO completion:nil];
   }

}
```

Comment: It's nice to know that this works on a split view controller. It's not a universal solution though -- if you try this from the first-tab controller in a tab bar controller (or a stand alone controller), you will get an error (Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x8a5df40> on <UITabBarController: 0x8e3bf20> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!). It does work on the root view controller of a navigation controller though.

Comment: @rdelmar It just made a sample project. the above code does work for root view controller as a navigation controller as well. I don't know if the above solution is the best, but it works as expected. I would like see if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you present the modal view controller from the viewDidAppear method of the detail view controller (with no animation), it will be the first thing you see. For example,

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (notLoggedIn) {
        UIViewController *modal = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Blue"];
        [self presentViewController:modal animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could still see the glance of UISplivewController before modal view controller is loaded. I found out what I had been doing wrong. I opened modal view controller with animation. I will vote up your answer. But for the future reference, I will post the answer that worked well..

Comment: @RedDevil, did you see that "glance" on the simulator or a device. I don't see that on either.

Comment: yes I did see a glance.. Since - (void)viewDidLoad is called before -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated.. placing the code in viewdidload solved the problem

Comment: since I am using ipad 2.. probably of slow processor I could see the glance.